# Cannot launch javascript alert on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner on html, CSS & JSS and I am trying to create a simple alert onclick button to test some concepts. I have created simple contact form with bootstrap design and I would just like to create an alert display the message content on click of "send" button. I have written some code down however the alert is not displaying onclick.

Here is my html file code:

```
<h1 class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft">Contact me</h1>
                <div class="barwrapper">
                    <div class="bar animate__animated animate__backInLeft animate__slow"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>Email</h2>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
                </div>
                <h2>Message</h2>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <input class="form-control" id="message" rows="3">
                </div>
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
                        <button  onclick="getInputValue();" class="btn btn-primary me-md-2" type="button" id="send">Send</button>
                    </div>
```

And here is my js file code:

```
function getInputValue()
{
    var inputVal = document.getElementById('#message').Value;

    alert(inputVal)
}
```

My js file seems correctly linked to my html file :

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: `var inputVal = document.getElementById('#message').Value;` would be `var inputVal = document.getElementById('message').Value;`

Comment: And `.value` with a lowercase V.

Comment: Use your developer console... Learn that case matters....

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got the code working. Duly noted for the developer console, I'll try to spend some time on tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, you need to declare your variable like this:

```
var inputVal = document.getElementById('message');
```

See the snippet below:

```js
var inputVal = document.getElementById('message');

function getInputValue() {
  alert(inputVal.value)
}
```

```html
<h1 class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft">Contact me</h1>
<div class="barwrapper">
  <div class="bar animate__animated animate__backInLeft animate__slow"></div>
</div>
<h2>Email</h2>
<div class="mb-3">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
</div>
<h2>Message</h2>
<div class="mb-3">
  <input class="form-control" id="message" rows="3"></input>
</div>
<div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
  <button onclick="getInputValue();" class="btn btn-primary me-md-2" type="button" id="send">Send</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So it seems it is still no working on my html page (obviously working here in the snippet).

When I run :

`var inputVal = document.getElementById('message');

function getInputValue() {
  alert(inputVal.value)
}`

I get no alert. However when I run :
`var inputVal = document.getElementById('message').value;

function getInputValue() {
  alert(inputVal)
}`

I get an "undefined" alert.

Comment: The code expects a value to be entered in the `message` input. If the Message is empty the alert will be empty. Also, I'm not sure what your local environment looks like but make sure you're calling your `<script></script>` right before the closing `</body>` tag in your HTML.

Comment: So after playing around with the code I followed your advice et put the script inside the html code right before de closing `</body>`and it worked. Still don't know why it is not working when I link a js file but at least I can move on so thanks a lot ! Learning programing is much tougher than it seems 

Comment: The reason it works when putting the script before `</body>` is because it will wait for the rest of the document to load before running the script. - It should also work with your external javascript file, however, you just need to make sure you're calling the file path properly.

Comment: Nevermind, I see now that you marked another answer correct. Still, happy to help! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought I marked yours correct (new on stackoverflow as well), just changed it to yours (hope it updates). Appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

getElementById requires only the document id string, without the #

```
function getInputValue()
{
    var inputVal = document.getElementById('message').value;
    alert(inputVal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft">Contact me</h1>
    <div class="barwrapper">
        <div class="bar animate__animated animate__backInLeft animate__slow"></div>
    </div>

    <h2>Email</h2>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
    </div>

    <h2>Message</h2>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" id="message" rows="3">
    </div>

    <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
        <button  onclick="getInputValue();" class="btn btn-primary me-md-2" type="button" id="send">Send</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Index.js:

```
function getInputValue()
{
    var inputVal = document.getElementById('message').value;

    alert(inputVal)
}
```